Deep-links does not open flutter app everytime
I tried to implement deeplinks into my flutter app. Now I am at a point where the deep-link works and opens the app if I send it via Discord and click "visit site". But when I send the link via Instagram or use it in a QR-Code it only opens up the link in the browser.
I am testing the app on a Samsung S10 with Android 12. Except Discord it always opens the Samsung Browser and not the app.
AndroidManifest.xml:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:label="example_project"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with YOUR_SCHEME://YOUR_HOST -->
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="example-app.at"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility?hl=en and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/event" />
        </intent>
    </queries>


</manifest>


Usage in App:
onPressed: () async {
                    final result = await Share.share(
                        'Tritt meiner Party auf Example bei: https://example-app.at/joinParty/${id}',
                        subject: 'Tritt meiner Party bei');

                    if (result.status == ShareResultStatus.success) {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }
                  },


I think you're missing something important here. Android needs to make sure that this domain belongs to you. So you need to provide an assetslinks.json via your host at .well-known/assetlinks.json.
 [{
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": 
    {
     "namespace": "android_app",
     "package_name": "com.example",
     "sha256_cert_fingerprints":["14:6D:E9:83:C5:73:06:50:D8:EE:B9:95:2F:34:FC:64:16:A0:83:42:E6:1D:BE:A8:8A:04:96:B2:3F:CF:44:E5"]
    }
}]

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks
